# my own banner ads in my android app like Google banner ads

Tags: android, ads

i want to add my own created ads display in my android app like google banner ads 
how i can archive that.

if using image view is this this possible ? than how to add animations any lib for that?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make your own AdView, I think you will only 2 option,

1. You can use ImageView with X seconds of refresh rate.
2. If you want to make animated ImageView, it is better to have [GIFView](http://www.geeks.gallery/how-to-display-the-animated-gif-image-in-android/)

Comment: thanks for suggestion!!